# Loading external and internal property files

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to load both external and internal property files for my app but I am having an issue with it. I have two property files, one is inside ***/src/main/resources***, let's call it p1.properties. The second file is located at my ***c:\poc\p2.properties***. So when I declared ***spring.config.location = file:c://poc/p2.properties***. It will only load the external one. then I try to add the ***classpath:myapp/src/main/resources*** but still it only loads the external file only. And throws an exception saying not able to find p1.properties. I don't want to use **PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer** to hard code my external file path. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here as well. I am using spring boot 2.0.4. I have another application with spring 1.5.x, i dont have the problem there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still facing the issue you can specify the internal property to be loaded like below from the command line argument.

```
-Dspring.config.location=file:c://poc/p2.properties,classpath:p1.properties
```

Hope this helps!